# infinite loop when i dispatch action after getting data w/subscribe

Tags: angular6, ngrx-store, rxjs6

i'm new in angular 6 and ngrx store. I try to dispatch action after get data subscribe from store but it make infinite loop and crash browser? What i was wrong . Some solution i find it using do/tap operator of rxjs but still not working. And when i use {{(feedState | async).loading}} for example , it alway return undefined .

my component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new FeedActions.GetFeedCategories());
    this.feedSubscription = this.store
      .pipe(
        select('feed'),
        map(data => {
          this.feedState = data;
          return data.categories;
        }),
        tap(data =>
          this.store.dispatch(
            new FeedActions.GetFeedItems({
              cat_id: data[this.selectedIndex],
              page: 0
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(data => {});
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The select operator will create an observable which emits every time the state of 'feed' is updated. This will fire the first time when you do your `FeedActions.GetFeedCategories()` but it will also fire again when the result of `FeedActions.GetFeedItems(...)` is added to the state, which will cause `FeedActions.GetFeedItmes(...)` to be executed again, and again, and again...

The simple solution is to add a take(1) into the pipe, so you only get a single fire of the map and tap operators:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new FeedActions.GetFeedCategories());
    this.feedSubscription = this.store
      .pipe(
        select('feed'),
        take(1),
        map(data => {
          this.feedState = data;
          return data.categories;
        }),
        tap(data =>
          this.store.dispatch(
            new FeedActions.GetFeedItems({
              cat_id: data[this.selectedIndex],
              page: 0
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(data => {});
  }
```

However, it may be worth considering splitting the concerns here - you've mixed the job of preparing the state with the job of selecting the state for display. A better solution may be something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(new FeedActions.GetFeedCategories());
    this.store.pipe(
        select('feed'),
        take(1),
        map(data => data.categories),
        tap(data =>
          this.store.dispatch(
            new FeedActions.GetFeedItems({
              cat_id: data[this.selectedIndex],
              page: 0
            })
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe(() => {});

      this.feedState = this.store.pipe(
          select('feed')
      );
  }
```

... then in your template, you can use `{{feedState | async}}?.loading` or whatever as needed.

The `async` pipe does the subscription for you and expects an observable, not a raw data field. In your example, this.feedState should be of type `Observable<FeedState>`, but it looks to be a raw data type (e.g. FeedState instead of Observable) from the code provided.

Comment: oh sorry i have busy i will test is now . im come from react to angular so reactive it is really weird. thanks for helpp . :D

Comment: wow its work as a charm . i im so stupid i should learn more reactive programming :D Thanks u so much , happy weekend :D

Comment: oh wait, why you have symbol ? in {{feedState | async}}?.loading :( i dont understand it

Comment: That's a null check @duykhanh - it just means the template will resolve to empty rather than causing an error if the observable emits a null or hasn't yet emitted.

Comment: Thank you @MarkHughes - your solution solves my problem! :)